# Geting new data into old data frame in R

Tags: r

I have an OD problem with getting new data data frame into old one.

```
old<-data.frame(O=c("I","A","B","D","R","F","A"),D=c("I","F","C","B","D","G","B"),F3=c(1:7))
new<-data.frame(O=c("F","D","R","F","A"),D=c("G","B","D","G","F"),F3=c(11,0,13,14,16))
old$OD<-paste(old$O, old$D, sep=" ")
new$OD<-paste(new$O, new$D, sep=" ")
```

The old data:

```
> old
  O D F3  OD
1 I I  1 I I
2 A F  2 A F
3 B C  3 B C
4 D B  4 D B
5 R D  5 R D
6 F G  6 F G
7 A B  7 A B
```

and the new one:

```
> new
  O D F3  OD
1 F G 11 F G
2 D B  0 D B
3 R D 13 R D
4 F G 14 F G
5 A F 16 A F
```

I want to substitude the old F3 value with the new one based on common OD.

I have tried:

```
Old_new1<-merge(old,new, by = "OD")


Old_new2<- ifelse(old$OD %in%  new$OD,new$F3,old$F3 )
Old_new2<-data.frame(old,Old_new2)
```

I wann to get:

```
> old_new
      O D F3  OD F3_new
    1 I I  1 I I  1
    2 A F  2 A F 16
    3 B C  3 B C  3
    4 D B  4 D B  0
    5 R D  5 R D 13
    6 F G  6 F G 14
    7 A B  7 A B  7
```

I want to be abel to compere it first befor substituting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a `data.table` `join` `on` the 'OD' and assign (`:=`) the 'F3' column values in 'new' (`i.F3`) to the 'F3' column in 'old'

```
library(data.table)
new$F3 <- as.integer(new$F3) # as the class for old 'F3' is `integer`
setDT(old)[new, F3 := i.F3, on = .(OD)]
old
#   O D F3  OD
#1: I I  1 I I
#2: A F 16 A F
#3: B C  3 B C
#4: D B  0 D B
#5: R D 13 R D
#6: F G 14 F G
#7: A B  7 A B
```

Comment: I would like to see the both old and new values side by side and be able to compare it, but for some reason it disaperes from the original input. I  even did A<-old befor making the changes in order to presever the old F3 values and it change the values in A aslo... where did I go wrong?

Comment: @TanyaValkanova  If you need to see that try `setDT(old)[new, on = .(OD)]` before the assignment.  You will find the columns in the old and the corresponding columns `i.` from 'new'.  By doing assignment `:=`, we are updating in place the 'old' column 'F3' with the corresponding value from 'new' 'F3'

Comment: I get only 5 rows from this the one in the new, when I do `setDT(new)[old, on = .(OD)]` I get 8 rows.

Comment: @TanyaValkanova  These are the five rows that have a matching 'OD'.  So, what it does is that while you assign `:=`, these values on those positions gets updated in the original 'old' dataset column 'F3'

Comment: @TanyaValkanova  Just to clarify what I said, if you do a `merge` with `all = TRUE`, it will give the rows with all the matching as well as non-matching 'OD'.  If there is not a match, it will be a `NA` i.e. `merge(old, new, by = 'OD', all = TRUE)`